# Flutter image cache for current session only

Tags: flutter, image, dart

I've built a music player app which automatically fetches songs from a server at start-up.

The issue is that, if I use NetworkImage to display the covers for the songs on an overview page, they are refetched everytime I leave the page and then return to it.

I already tried using CachedNetworkImage, but I don't want to store the song covers in the users cache. The images should persist for one session and then be disposed.

I could probably clear the cache everytime the user closes the app but there has to be a better way

Answer (score 0):

You could try storing the images in memory while app is running, then dispose when app is closed.
Third party libraries such as `flutter_cache_manager` can help achieve this.
It allows persistence of images for app session's duration.

Comment: In my experience using the cache manager to download, store and then show the image as a MemoryImages is way slower than using a NetworkImage with the corresponding URL directly

Comment: `NetworkImage` in a nutshell: Everytime you navigate away from the screen and return to it, images will be refetched from server (consumes bandwith, and also slow). Caching image in memory using pattern provider reduces number of network requests, making your app more responsikve and efficient. Could you elaborate why you think NetworkImage is faster?

Comment: The page was only slower because of my placeholder for the image while loading, so that problem is solved. Nevertheless the new issue, now that I'm trying the cache manager again, is flickering every time the images are reloaded. It seems they are only stored on the disk but not in memory or something